# How to assign parameters from a SimpleXMLElement Object to variables?

Tags: php, object

I'm posting user data to a payment gateway using the following script :

```
$map_url = "https://paynetzuat.atomtech.in/paynetz/epi/fts?login=160&pass=Test@123&ttype=NBFundTransfer&prodid=NSE&amt=50&txncurr=INR&txnscamt=0&clientcode=007&txnid=12345&date=19/09/2015&custacc=1234567890&udf1=vinodBisen&udf2=mymail@gmail.com&udf3=9890933093&udf4=mybillingaddress&ru=http://mysite.in/thankyou.html";

if (($response_xml_data = file_get_contents($map_url))===false) {
    echo "Error fetching XML\n";
} else {
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $data = simplexml_load_string($response_xml_data);

    if (!$data) {
        echo "Error loading XML\n";
        foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
            echo "\t", $error->message;
        }
    } else {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($data);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

And getting a response as below:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [MERCHANT] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [RESPONSE] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [url] => https://mysite.api.url.com/fts
                    [param] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => NBFundTransfer
                            [1] => 524014
                            [2] => K30ZsUL2Z5mD8NN1xS6FxIuV0YlOS2e1KPEKv0fT0Ms%3D
                            [3] => 1
                        )    
                )    
        )    
)
```

I want to get each response into a separate variable to create a link using the dynamic response received by the payment gateway API.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over `RESPONSE` and then over `param` to extract names and values by casting them to `string`:

```
foreach($data->MERCHANT->RESPONSE as $response) {

    $responseData = array(
        'url' => (string)$response->url
    );

    foreach($response->param as $param) {
        $responseData[(string)$param->attributes()->name] = (string)$param;
    }

    print_r($responseData);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://paynetzuat.atomtech.in/paynetz/epi/fts
    [ttype] => NBFundTransfer
    [tempTxnId] => 524142
    [token] => BL%2BmNz1kIv9%2FzTk8ei9iAxNmMGUJtt5jMip9Bfw1hG0%3D
    [txnStage] => 1
)
```

Then if you wanted to echo the `token`, you could simply do this:

```
echo $responseData['token'];
```

If there is only one response, you can can skip iterating over `RESPONSE`:

```
$responseData = array(
    'url' => (string)$data->MERCHANT->RESPONSE->url
);

foreach($data->MERCHANT->RESPONSE->param as $param) {
    $responseData[(string)$param->attributes()->name] = (string)$param;
}

print_r($responseData);
```